# jQuery Accordion dynamically add more sections?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic, accordion

On my ASP.net MVC 3.0 
I have a View looks in that i have a section of code

```
<div id="accordion">
    @Html.Action("Action", "Controller")
</div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Another Content", "Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "accordion",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
HttpMethod = "POST"
}, new { @class = "standard button", id = "AddAnother" })
```

The Generated HTML markup for the above code will look like this

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#"> Title</a> </h3>
<div> Body Content </div>
</div>
<a href="Add" id="AddAnother"> Add</a>
```

Script i have on my page is like this

```
$("#AddAnother").click(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", ":last");
});
```

Every time if Add link is clicked it adds another h3/div section to with in the main accordion section as bellow

```
<div id="accordion">

<h3><a href="#"> Title</a> </h3>
    <div> Body Content </div>

<h3><a href="#"> Title</a> </h3>
    <div> Body Content </div>

<h3><a href="#"> Title</a> </h3>
    <div> Body Content </div>

</div>
```

My Problem is.
when ever add link is clicked
it goes through three steps.

```
1)Destroy accordion

2)Recreate Accordion

3)Add New H3/Div
```

I don't want this way

I want is to follow this order

```
1) destroy accordion

2) Add new h3/div to the block

3) Recreate Accordion
```

Can any one help me to correct this in in my scrip

```
  $("#AddAnother").click(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", ":last");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Another Content", "Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "accordion",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "destroyAccordion",
    OnSuccess = "createAccordion"
}, new { @class = "standard button", id = "AddAnother" })
```

JS:

```
function destroyAccordion () {
    $("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
}

function createAccordion() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", ":last");
}
```