# MVC action from jQuery append()?

Tags: jquery, append

I want to append MVC action with jQuery append()

How can I do that?

```
 $("#AnotherErx").click(function () {
        $("#accordion")
                .append(@Html.Action("ErxView", "Medication"))
                .accordion("destroy")
                .accordion({ fillSpace: true })
                .accordion("option", "active", ":last")
        ;
        });
```

any help

Comment: -1. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: never mind i got my answer thanks

Comment: @maxedison can you please explain why my question makes no sense? All that i was asking was apped('<h3>text<h3><div>content</div>') works instead of static html i wanted to render dynamic html to the append(). And this question can be understood by any ASP.Net MVC Developer

Comment: @HaBo, if you got your answer then either delete your question or provide details on the answer so that others may benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, don't append using the @html keyword.

You can append a regular anchor tag with all the attributes filled in.

Essentially you have the append right I think now simply append "`<a href="you controller and cation">your value</a>`"

I hope this is what you are asking.  If not please let me know and i'll try to help further

Comment: I have my question explained more in detail here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748608/jquery-accordion-dynamically-add-more-sections/7748731#comment9438437_7748731) and it is answered by @Samuel Liew that is working perfect for my requirement